# How can I get this JSON Object List from this API into my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I've googled for probably over 6 hours now and none of the solutions I found could help me. What I'm looking for is to get this Object List "http://poe.ninja/api/Data/GetCurrencyOverview?league=Abyss" into a variable named Data or Currency.

Till now I've been using something along the lines of this:

```
var data
var currency = ""
var url = "http://poe.ninja/api/Data/GetCurrencyOverview?league=Abyss"

var myInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
  mode: "cors"
};

function getJSON() {
  fetch(url, myInit).then(function(response) {
    return response
  }).then(function(data) {
    currency = data
    document.getElementById("mirror").innerHTML += currency
    for (var x in currency) {
      document.getElementById("mirror").innerHTML += x + "<p>"
    }
  });
}
```

*The goal of the html edits is to just see if it works at all. Had some issues with opaque respons. As I'm interested in the Body(I think)*

I am getting:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on
>   'Window': The provided value is not of type
>   `(sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)`
>       at getJSON (PoECurrency.html:24)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (PoECurrency.html:48)

Anyone that can help me get this objectlist?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` means.  That's a _response_ header.

Comment: That API isn't cors enabled. You need to use a proxy either on server you control or third party service